# How to override property with square brackets in springboot 2.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, environment-variables

I need a way to override property with square brackets in springboot 2.0.1 version. I tried as per mentioned in link - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0
but no luck. May be not supported for 2.0.1 release

eg. parley.broker[0].host=localhost

Comment: You mean replacing a certain element in a list ?

Comment: I want a way to override `parley.broker[0].host` property through environment variable. I cant use environment variable with square brackets as it is not allowed

Comment: Tried underscore already ? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0#lists-1